# How do you move large industrial robots?

Tags: robotic-arm, movement

I know how they are moved on to a lorry/truck to be taken somewhere but when industrial robots are being built how are they moved around the production centre.

Comment: why do you believe that an answer of a few sentences would contain sufficient information on which to base your startup?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Da Mango, but I'm afraid that questions which are as broad as this are off-topic because answers would need to be too long. As it says in [ask] *If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much*. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so please take a look at [ask], [about] and the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) for advice on writing a good question.

Answer (score 1):

As jsotola's comment suggests, this Q&A site cannot give you what you need, and the best we can do is likely to be opinion-based. Here are some things to try anyway.

- Keep reading this web site. Its pointillist specificity will eventually fill in its broad scope.
- Many amateur robots differ from industrial robots only in degree (like size, power, precision, capability), not in kind. Search the web.
- Some high school and college undergrad programs (e.g. FIRST) publish their designs. Search the web.
- Manufacturers publish details about their products. Search the web.
- Find one or more mentors to guide you.

Good luck! Even if you don't make a career of robotics, it's a great hobby.